# Averaging variables of smaller polygons to larger polygons in R using the SF package

Tags: r, sf

Still getting used to the language of GIS with R so please bear with me.

I have [this public dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13vOV-gRdvTLQ14y9wnzw3tdgCm1jxiWE).

It has two levels of political boundaries: `ADM1` and `ADM2`.

I am currently doing everything (i.e. plotting, calculations, etc.) for `ADM2` which is each of the 2,440+ municipalities in Mexico because that is how the geometry is determined. However, I would like to calculate averages per states (`ADM1`) and start working with those by sort of "dissolving", if you will, the geometry of municipalities (`ADM2`) into geometries of (`ADM1)`.

So far I have imported it:

```
library (sf)
library (dplyr)

mexi_sf<-read_sf( dsn = getwd()
       , layer = "MexicoCaseStudy"
       , stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
```

Fixed some labels and changed some classes:

```
 mexi_sf$ADM1NAME<-str_replace_all(mexi_sf$ADM1NAME, 
                c("M.xico" = "México", "Nuevo Le.n" = "Nuevo León","San Luis Potos."="San Luis Potosí","Quer.taro de Arteaga"="Querétaro de Arteaga"))
mexi_sf$ADM1NAME<-as.factor(mexi_sf$ADM1NAME)
mexi_sf$ADM2NAME<-as.factor(mexi_sf$ADM2NAME)
mexi_sf$ADM1CODE<-as.numeric(mexi_sf$ADM1CODE)
mexi_sf$ADM2CODE<-as.numeric(mexi_sf$ADM2CODE)
```

Changed some outliers:

```
  for (row in 1:nrow(mexi_sf)){
    if (mexi_sf$FOODEXP[row]==-9999){
     mexi_sf$FOODEXP[row]=-1
    }}
```

Here is my attempt to average the variable `FOODEXP` by `ADM1NAME`.

```
  average_food_exp<-mexi_sf%>%
  group_by(ADM1NAME)%>%
  mutate(meanFOODEXP=mean(FOODEXP))
```

And obvs something is wrong because I can't plot it:

```
    big_food_map_sf_trial<-tm_shape(average_food_exp,style="quantiles",n=8)+
  tm_fill(col="meanFOODEXP",palette="Reds",title="mean FOODEXP (MXN 2004)")+
  tm_text("ADM1NAME",size=0.5)+
  tm_layout(legend.outside =FALSE)+
   tm_borders(col="black")+
  tm_credits("Source: CIMMYT, June 2004, Mexican municipalities below food poverty line, year 2000.",position=c("left","bottom"),size=0.75)

save_tmap(tm=big_food_map_sf_trial,filename="big_food_map_sf_trial.png",width = 17,height=7)
```

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `summarize(meanFOODEXP=mean(FOODEXP))` (not mutate) after the group_by.

E.g.

```
library(sf)
example(st_read)  ## to read 'nc' object
nc %>% group_by(row_number() %% 4) %>% summarize(mean(BIR74))
```

I just make a 4-group dummy there, but you should be able to do

```
average_food_exp<-mexi_sf%>%
group_by(ADM1NAME)%>%
 summarize(meanFOODEXP = mean(FOODEXP))
```

It's always a good idea to `ungroup` afterwards if you only `mutate`, because that maintains the rows (and the groups) but applies the summary value to the original rows.